# Are there any theorem relating transcendency/irrationality of Euler's constant and the Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: reference-request, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers, riemann-hypothesis, euler-mascheroni-constant

Several formulations of the Riemann hypothesis can be given in terms of Euler’s constant. For example,

> Theorem (Nicolas 1981) The Riemann hypothesis holds if and only if all the primorial numbers $N_k = p_1p_2 · · · p_k$ with $k ≥ 2$ satisfy $$\dfrac{N_k}{\phi(N_k) \ln \ln N_k} > e^{\gamma}.$$

or

> Theorem (Nicolas 2012) For each integer $n ≥ 2$, the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the statement that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup (\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)} - e^{\gamma} \ln \ln n ) \sqrt{\ln n} = e^γ (4 + γ − \ln (4π)) $$

After searching quite a lot on internet, it seems that *only* constant *itself* appears in connections with the Riemann hypothesis. Are there any theorem at all relating *transcendency/irrationality* of $\gamma$ and the Riemann hypothesis?

Comment: Even if $e^{\gamma}$ could be shown to be irrational (which does not follow from the irrationality of $\gamma$), this would barely allow us to prove the Riemann hypothesis with the second shown theorem. The first theorem, containing an inequality, would be even more useless for this task. So it is hard to imagine that there is any relationsship between the two problems : $(1)$ is $\gamma$ rational ? $(2)$ Is RH true ?